# cleaning raw text files with vertical bars and converting them into csv

Tags: python, r, pandas, csv

I have a huge raw dataset( 4k lines each text file) with a lot of vertical bars and spaces.

```
      |group call| pvt call |phone call|group busy| pvt busy |phone busy|     
 time |total     |total     |total     |total     |total     |total     |  %  
period| sec  cnt | sec   cnt| sec   cnt| sec   cnt| sec   cnt| sec   cnt | usage

00:00 | 4323  548|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0| 18%

00:15 | 4125  479|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0| 17%

00:30 | 3071  395|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0| 13%

00:45 | 3514  447|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0| 14%

01:00 | 3081  383|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0|    0    0| 13%
```

I want to convert it into a csv file. 
The parser that I built using python and pandas only reads csv values. How can I do so?
The csv file should look something like:

```
time_pd,group_call_t_s,group_call_t_c,pvt_call_t_sec,pvt_call_t_c,phone_call_t_sec,phone_call_t_c,group_busy_t_sec,group_busy_t_c,pvt_busy_t_sec, pvt_busy_t_c,phone_busy_t_sec, phone_busy_t_c, per_usage
00:00,4323,548,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18%
00:15,4125,479,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17%
00:30,3071,395,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13%
00:45,3514,447,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14%
01:00,3081,383,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13%
01:15,4017,470,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18%
01:30,4767,555,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18%
```

Comment: If you can guarantee that there will not be embedded spaces in any of the fields, then try `gsub('[ |]+', ',', readLines(filename))` for basic `sep=` conversion. Your column naming is a bit more work, though.

Comment: missing your attempt for solution. will provide solution when you provide your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

If all files have the same header structure, you can read the data part, assign the headers, and then save to CSV:

```
data = pd.read_csv("file1.txt", sep=r'\s*\|?\s*', header=None, skiprows=3)
#      0     1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12   13
#0  00:00  4323  548   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  18%
#1  00:15  4125  479   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  17%
#2  00:30  3071  395   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  13%
#3  00:45  3514  447   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  14%
#4  01:00  3081  383   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  13%
data.columns = "time_pd","group_call_t_s","group_call_t_c",...
data.to_csv("file1.csv", index=None)
```

Comment: I always get this error.
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'time_pd,group_call_t_s,group_call_t_c,pvt_call_t_sec,pvt_call_t_c,phone_call_t_sec,phone_call_t_c,group_busy_t_sec,group_busy_t_c,pvt_busy_t_sec,pvt_busy_t_c,phone_busy_t_sec,phone_busy_t_c,per_usage' was passed